# Remote performance monitor on WinCE 6

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-ce, performance-testing

I want to monitor performance of the application installed on Win
CE device. I copied `cemgrc.exe`, `tcpipc.dll` and `cetstub.dll`.

I made one `connect2PC.bat` file using `CEMGRC.EXE/S/T:TCPIPC.DLL/Q /D:xx.xx.xx.xxxx.5555`
command. When I run this bat file on WinCE device it shows Application CEMGRC.exe encountered serious error and needs to shutdown. What could be the reason? From where can I get CEMGRC.exe   file for WinCE 6.

Comment: waiting for comments..solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. connect2PC.bat file was corrupted, I've re-created it and it worked very well.